# изменение высоты изображения jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, мне нужна функция которая будет проверять изображение в каждом блоке .news-img-area, и если это изображение имеет высоту больше 500, то изменять высоту этого изображения на 500.
спасибо

Comment: зачем функцию? если можно в css прописать "max-height: 500px"

Answer (score 2):

Зачем Javascript:

```
.news-img-area img {
  max-height: 500px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Но, если что:

```
const styleMutation = () => (   
  [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.news-img-area img'), (el) => 
     (Object.assign(el.style, { maxHeight: '500px', width: 'auto'} ))))
```

или, дословно следуя вашему вопросу:

```
const evilMutation = () => (   
  [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('.news-img-area img'), (el) => 
     ((el.offsetHeight > 500) && (el.height = 500))))
```

Но тут уже надо следить, чтобы изображения к тому моменту были полностью загружены и значение `innerHeight` уже устаканилось. Также, CSS-стили визуально перекрывают значение `height`, т.е. лучше использовать их.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('img').each(function(i,elem){
 if ($(this).height() > 100)
  $(this).css({'height' : '100px'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://galerey-room.ru/images/0_3d5b5_7f4a5b0b_orig.png" />
<br>
<img src="http://www.plandmsc.com/images/pictures/personalPictures/yellow-gerbera-500x500.jpg" />
```